# echo 3 statements based wc -l count number returned in output

Tags: shell, awk, xargs

Team, I have below command that is working fine but I am enhancing it to get result like below

my goal is to report the count and display statement with it.

I have three conditions to be met

1 - if result = 0 mounts not found

2 - if result = 1-64, mounts found under 64

3 - if result = 64+, mounts found above 64

if count is 0 I want to output:

```
0 mounts found on this hostname
```

if 1-64 mounts found, then I want to say whatever number is found

```
x mounts found on hostname.
```

if anything beyond 64 mounts are found, then i want to say

```
x mounts found on hostname that are more than 64
```

```
mount | grep csi | grep -e /dev/sd | wc -l && echo "mounts found on $HOSTNAME"
```

I am trying to learn how to compare returned count to 64 and displace statement accordingly. I need a single line shell command for all this and not a multiple coz i need to fit it in ansible shell module.

sample output:

```
mount | grep csi
```

```
tmpfs on /var/lib/kubelet/pods/abaa868f-2109-11ea-a1f8-ac1f6b5995dc/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/csi-nodeplugin-token-type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
/host/dev/sdc on /var/lib/kubelet/pods/11ea-a1f8-ac1f6b5995dc/volumes/kubernetes.io~csi/ea6728b2-08d0-5fb7-b93a-5f63e49f770c/mount type iso9660 (ro,relatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,fsc,readahead=4096)
```

```
mount | grep csi | grep /dev/sd
```

```
/host/dev/sdc on /var/lib/kubelet/pods/11ea-a1f8-ac1f6b5995dc/volumes/kubernetes.io~csi/b93a-5f63e49f770c/mount type iso9660 (ro,relatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,fsc,readahead=4096)
```

any hint why is this not working below?

tried solution: with awk and comparison operator

```
mount | grep -Ec '/dev/sd.*\<csi' | awk '$0 = 0 { printf "No mounts found", $0,"TRUE" ; } ($0 > 0 && $0 <= 64)  { print "Mounts are less than 64", $0 ;} $0 > 64  { print "Mounts are more than 64", $0 ;}'
```

output:

```
node1
```

expected:

```
node1 No mounts found
```

Comment: the output message for `0` and `1-64` is essentially the same

Comment: why is it ? I want different output for 0 and for anything <64. need to output 3 statements for three conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With extended and optimized pipeline:

```
mount | grep -Ec '/dev/sd.*\<csi' \
| awk '{ print $0,"mounts found on hostname"($0>64? " that are more than 64." : ".") }'
```

`grep`'s `-c` option - suppress normal output; instead print a count of  matching  lines

The symbols `\<` and `\>` respectively match the empty string at the beginning and end  of  a  word.

Comment: When execute I am not getting any output and its always 0 so is this pattern correct in your solution?

example: I get one mount for `mount | grep csi | grep /dev/sd` but when i use yours i get nothing `mount | grep -Ec '/dev/sd.* csi'`

Comment: @AhmFM then `csi` comes before `/dev/sd` or has no space before it. If in your question you showed the output of `mount` that you want to parse it'd help a lot towards helping you write a tool to parse that output.

Comment: oh my bad: added the output now. please check

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot . works. can you please explain me what is < in above and why is is \? can you please explain your expression before awk

Comment: @AhmFM, see my notations

Comment: I have one clarification: where is it printing `mounts not found` when shell result is 0? I have edited my question. Please have a look at the conditions

Comment: I added my tried solution in end of question: can you please hint what am i missing? its not printing expected output.